# Should I use rails admin for end user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I'm building an API management apps where every user able to find their own token for making an API request. Every end user will have to manage their own API access, they should also have access to many other custom endpoint.

At the moment, the Rails Admin is being used for the internal administration. Such as CRUD of "AdminUser", "Payment", and other internal system management.

The question is: Should I use Rails Admin's feature for this functionality (as in exposing admin control to every regular user)? Or should I just create a separate admin section for the general user with a standard form?

I'm not very experienced in Rails Admin implementation. So, I wonder if I should use it too for the end user.

Thanks for your time & help!

---

### Update

Some of my basic concern about using Rails Admin to me is that: Rails Admin is for developer or internal adminstration. There will be some risk of giving a wrong permission to the end user

Answer (score 1):

Rails Admin is a quick and easy way to access all the data in your app. It can be customised to restrict access to certain models or fields, however you will have to use the Rails Admin DSL for that, and it kind of defeats the purpose of using Rails Admin if you need to do lots of customising.

A danger is also that if you did not set it up properly, the default is to expose all data to the users.

Since the functions you want to expose to the user doesn't sound too complex, it wouldn't be too much effort to write your own.